# Implementing Interface - Method Signature Error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, interface

I have this interface:

```
public interface IAppointmentDAO extends IAppointmentDate {
    void close();

    void deleteAppointment(long id);

    Appointment getAppointment(long id);

    List<Appointment> getGroomerAppointmentsByDate(int groomerId, Calendar date);

    List<Appointment> getGroomerAppointmentsByDate(int groomerId,
            Calendar date, int appId);

    List<Event> getGroomerEventsByDate(int groomerId, Calendar date);

    boolean isEmptyDate(int day, int month, int year, int groomerId);
```

I have a class which implements the interface. It has this method:

```
   @Override
        public boolean isEmptyDate(int day, int month, int year, int groomerId) {
            Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
            today.set(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0);
            today.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            Calendar tomorrow = Calendar.getInstance();
            tomorrow.set(year, month, day + 1, 0, 0, 0);
            tomorrow.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            String[] insertArgs = new String[] {
                    String.valueOf(today.getTimeInMillis()),
                    String.valueOf(tomorrow.getTimeInMillis()),
                    String.valueOf(groomerId) };
            Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(
                    SQLiteConstants.COUNT_APPOINTMENTS_FOR_DATE, insertArgs);
            try {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst())
                    return cursor.getInt(0) > 0 ? false : true;
                return true;
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
```

We can see that the signature of the method is the same as the bottom signature in the interface. However, my class has an error saying it does not implement all the methods from the interface. I do the quickfix to make the class implement the methods from the interface and it provides the class with this method:

```
@Override
    public boolean isEmptyDate(int day, int month, int year, long id) {
        return false;
    }
```

Why does Android Studio think my interface `isEmptyDate` method takes an `id` parameter of type `long`?

Comment: Try cleaning the cache (File - Invalidate caches / Restart) and rebuilding the project

Comment: Looking weird to me.

Comment: If two version of same method name available then need to implement both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the method with long id parameter comes from IAppointmentDate interface.

Comment: Good thinking, but not the case this time. In my interface the `boolean isEmptyDate(int day, int month, int year, int groomerId);` is greyed out, which signifies that it is never used.

Comment: This may be correct (that it is never used) as nobody calls it. Can you post full code of both those interfaces - IAppointmentDAO and IAppointmentDate ?

Comment: I see it is in the IAppointmentDate interface. Silly me. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Seems like issue with method.
1. just initialize one local boolean variable  with false.
2. assign cursor.getInt(0) to above variable.
3. Return this variable after finally.
4. it should solve your problem

Comment: This doesn't even relate to the question.